# Adding Time Limit parameter to Ola hallengren Index Maintenance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, ola-hallengren

I would like to limit the duration of the index maintenance procedure of Ola Hallengren to be 7200 seconds (2 Hours)

I found parameter TimeLimit defined as: Set the time, in seconds, after which no commands are executed. By default, the time is not limited.

Does this mean if a command is already running and the time limit reach it will force it to stop or will continue and will not run any command after ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a command is already running and the time limit reach it: will continue and will not run any command after.
To answer your question I saw stored procedure definition. Find keyword @TimeLimit

Comment: That means, if the time limit is set to 5 hours (18000 seconds) and if a new command is started at 4 hr 59 minutes, then once the time limit reach it to 5 hrs it will still continue that current command but no further commands will be performed after that, correct?